# How do I make "startx iceweasel" launch full-screen?

Tags: x11, raspbian, iceweasel

I've done a clean install of Raspian Lite on my Rasperry Pi (there is no desktop environment installed). I'd like a kiosk-mode browser running fullscreen without having to worry about maintaining/securing a DE.

After installing Raspbian Lite, I did `apt-get install iceweasel` and `apt-get install x-window-system`.

I'm now able to login and run `startx iceweasel` and I get a functional iceweasel as required; however it's only about a quarter of the screen!

The console I ran `startx` from was using the full screen; but after launching X/iceweasel the used area got smaller.

Ideally I'd like it to inherit the resolution the console was already using, but I'd settle for having to provide them manually if that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox stores the size of the last window in the profile. As of Iceweasel 38, the relevant file is `xulstore.json` (the size is also recorded in other files but this is the one that matters when launching Firefox unless you're using a session manager extension).

Normally you'll end up with the same window size as the last run. If you need to modify that, edit `xulstore.json`. The setting is
`"chrome://browser/content/browser.xul"` → `"main-window"` → `"width"`, `"height"`.

Comment: When I tried going to that chrome:// address, I just get another addressbar/etc. rendered inside the window! :/
Can I edit the file by hand? (I need a solution I can script ultimately)

Comment: @DannyTuppeny You *need* to edit the file by hand, AFAIK. That string is a key in the file, the fact that it looks like a URL is just a coincidence.

Comment: Haha, oops! I just tried this, and set it to 1920x1080 and it works perfectly! I still have an overscan border, but I already know how to fix that. It's not perfect (I need to create the profile first, and I want everything in a script from a clean Raspain setup) but it's a huge step closer. Thanks! :)